# Add `tikzpicture` environment to the list of choices for AUCTex's environment insertion shortcut?

Tags: latex, auctex

I use AUCTex for all my Latex needs, and it works great. However, I wanted to insert a `tikzpicture` environment in my document, and I pushed the key `C-c C-e` for environments, but `tikzpicture` is not listed amongst the choices. Is there a way to include the `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}` environment in the list of AUCTex environments? I am not sure what variable I would need to change or how in my dotfile. I use Spacemacs, so I would probably need to append something to the list of environments,right?

Comment: If there is a `\usepackage{tikz}` line in the preamble, I would expect to find `tikzpicture` in the environment list.  It does for me without any intervention on my part.

Comment: @FranBurstall I will have to give that a try. I ran into this issue before adding the `\usepackage{tikz}` in the preamble. I did not think that the list of environments was sensitive to the list of packages used, since the other environments like `equation` or such, never seemed to depend on the packages. But it is a good idea to do a little experiment. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out. A user might need to check the final 3 parenthesis, but this code worked to add the environment. I added the following lines to my `.spacemacs` file.

```
;; Add latex environments to list of environments.
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'add-my-latex-environments)
(defun add-my-latex-environments ()
  (LaTeX-add-environments
   '("tikzpicture" LaTeX-env-label)))
```

Answer (score 1):

AucTeX automatically [provides a list of environments](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Environments.html#Environments) for you to insert. This includes a set of 'default' environments, based on a hard-coded set of environments commonly associated with the `documentclass` of your file.

Additionally, AucTeX parses the header of your file, and if it detects any packages that provide additional environments, these are added to the list. This functionality depends on you telling [AUCTeX to parse your file automatically](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Parsing-Files.html#Parsing-Files):

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
(setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
```

You can also manually tell AUCTeX to reparse your file, if you don't want it done automatically. The command `TeX-normal-mode`, bound to `C-c C-n` by default, serves this purpose.

There may be exceptions where you need to manually add an environment. However, I have just tested this with Emacs 28.0.50 and AUCTeX 13.0.5, and the `tikzpicture` environment is properly detected when your file contains the `\usepackage{tikz}` macro.